# Adding extra type parameter to interface method prevents override

Tags: java, generics, overriding

The following code doesn't compile, and this surprised me. Can anyone explain why?

Params.java:

```
public interface Params {
    <E> E test(Class<E> cls);

    interface MoreParams extends Params {
        @Override
        <E, F> E test(Class<E> cls);
    }
}
```

Compiling:

```
Params.java:6: error: name clash: <E#1,F>test(Class<E#1>) in
    MoreParams and <E#2>test(Class<E#2>) in Params have the same
    erasure, yet neither overrides the other
        <E, F> E test(Class<E> cls);
                 ^
  where E#1,F,E#2 are type-variables:
    E#1 extends Object declared in method <E#1,F>test(Class<E#1>)
    F extends Object declared in method <E#1,F>test(Class<E#1>)
    E#2 extends Object declared in method <E#2>test(Class<E#2>)
Params.java:5: error: method does not override or implement a
    method from a supertype
        @Override
        ^
2 errors
```

In case it's relevant, I'm using `java-8-oracle`, `javac` version `1.8.0_25`.

It seems like the extra generic type parameter has no tangible effect on the type signature, so why does it break the override?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may have to do with binary compatibility, though the exact error message you are getting may possibly be confusing.

Think about code written before adding the `MoreParams` interface:

```
Params params = new ParamsSubClass();
String str1 = params.test(String.class);
String str2 = params.<>test(String.class);
String str3 = params.<String>test(String.class);
```

When you instead of our artificial `ParamsSubClass`, use a class like `MoreParamsSubClass`, then the lines involving `str1` and `str2` will still work, *however* the line involving `str3` will no longer work, because two type parameters are to be expected, hence the code is not binary compatible.

So it looks like you cannot override a method when you change the type parameters, as that will break binary compatability.